# Objective-C how to convert nsdata from web service to nsarray

Tags: objective-c, web-services

How do i convert id to an array?

I have an apple app that talks to a server.

Issue i have is the app returns the data in the form of id however i need to convert this to an array as the actual returned data looks like the following.

```
[["30","2",1],["15","67",1],["30","4",1]]
```

It is actually the output from a mysql server

The actual app code looks like the following

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"blah blah"]];

    NSURL_Layer * connection = [[NSURL_Layer alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [connection setCompletitionBlock:^(id obj, NSError *err) {

        if (!err) {
            //Need to convert the id to nsarray here, dunno how
        } else {
            //There was an error
        }

    }];
    [connection start];
```

The NSURL.h

```
-(id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req;

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSURLConnection * internalConnection;
@property (nonatomic,copy)NSURLRequest *request;
@property (nonatomic,copy)void (^completitionBlock) (id obj, NSError * err);


-(void)start;
```

NSURL.m

```
-(id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)req {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setRequest:req];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)start {

    container = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    internalConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[self request] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if(!sharedConnectionList)
        sharedConnectionList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [sharedConnectionList addObject:self];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [container appendData:data];

}

//If finish, return the data and the error nil
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    if([self completitionBlock])
        [self completitionBlock](container,nil);

    [sharedConnectionList removeObject:self];

}

//If fail, return nil and an error
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    if([self completitionBlock])
        [self completitionBlock](nil,error);

    [sharedConnectionList removeObject:self];

}
```

Update:

i have added

```
    NSURL_Layer * connection = [[NSURL_Layer alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [connection setCompletitionBlock:^(id obj, NSError *err) {

        if (!err) {     
           NSError* error;          
           NSArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:obj options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
        } else {
            //There was an error
        }

    }];
    [connection start];
```

but returns error

```
error   NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840
```

_userInfo   NSDictionary *  1 key/value pair
[0] (null)  @"NSDebugDescription" : @"Invalid value around character 0."

Update: I put

```
NSLog(@"Data as string:%@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:obj encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

which gave me a strange feedback. As a result i looked at my url request full code is below.

```
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"unique_id=%@&unique_password=%@",ServerUniqueID,ServerPassword];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"blah blah"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURL_Layer * connection = [[NSURL_Layer alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    [connection setCompletitionBlock:^(id obj, NSError *err) {

        if (!err)
        {
            NSError* error;
            NSArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithData: obj] options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Data as string:%@", [[NSString alloc]initWithData:obj encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);

            int temp = array.count;

        }
        else
        {
            //There was an error
        }
    }];
    [connection start];
```

if i remove

```
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

it works

if its in it dosn't so i have a whole new issue to look into.

Comment: You don't need a cast: if you know it's an `NSArray`, call `objectForIndex:` on your `id`, and the compiler will take it just fine.

Comment: wouldn't i need to know the number of array in the obj, this is unknown and could be any

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but he has NSData only, no?

Comment: `NSLog(@"Data as string:%@", [NSString alloc]initWithData:obj encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you save the bytes into a container variable, alas the id infact NSData 
 (note id is just a 'wildcard pointer' that means ANY objC object)

so your id is NSData and from what you show it seems to be 3 json arrays... but no real JSON... (["30","2",1]["15","67",1]["30","4",1] isn't anything)

EITHER make the server send you JSON and THAT you can parse into a dictionary/array using NSJSONSerialization
OR write a custom separator to convert the data

Comment: hi, I've changed my service so it is now giving me [["30","2",1],["15","67",1],["30","4",1]] and tried using                 NSArray* array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:obj options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
 and its giving me error error NSError * domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840 0x78f2fb00

Comment: @Ineedhelp That is not JSON.

Comment: @quellish sure it is. array with 3 subarrays each with 3 string elements

Comment: @Daji-Djan, the NSError he is getting is indicating the data is corrupt or not in the indicated format. It won't parse as JSON.

Comment: this is what is confusing me, if i use a webbroswer to access php i get  [["30","2",1],["15","67",1],["30","4",1]]         try the above code both original updating I'm constantly fighting same error

Comment: @quellish yes indeed, but the code above IS json -- so yeah.. something must be different than what the OP shows

Comment: @Ineedhelp print it as quellish proposed

Comment: hi there, i did and realised I've made a massive mistake/dismissed wrong bit of code. Thanks for you help, i got a whole new section to look into now.